# How can I update an array within an object in react useState Hook

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, dynamic, state

I am trying to create a nested dynamic form in React. My goal is to be able to add days to the form dynamically as well as exercises inside the day.

Here is what my state looks like:

```
const [formFields, setFormFields] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    price: '',
    duration: '',
    description: '',
    daysPerWeek: '',
    allExercises: [
      {
        day: 'Monday',
        exercises: [
          {
            name: '',
            sets: '',
            reps: '',
            link: '',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
```

I am able to add a new day with this method

```
function addDay() {
    const newDay = {
      day: '',
      exercises: [
        {
          name: '',
          sets: '',
          reps: '',
          link: '',
        },
      ],
    };
    setFormFields((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      allExercises: [...prev.allExercises, newDay],
    }));
  }
```

But I want to have a button that will populate only the exercises array inside a specific day.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```js
setFormFields((prev) => ({
  ...prev,
  allExercises: prev.allExercises.map(x => {
    if (x.day !== 'Tuesday') {
      return x;
    }
    return {...x, exercises: [...x.exercises, ...newExercisesForTuesday]};
  }),
}));
```

You may want to consider using `useReducer` if things get more complex than this though.

Answer (score 0):

i provide a sample code here
you must pass a specific day to a func , loop for specific day and change it

```
[https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-frog-w6dr3l?file=/src/App.js][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do something like this:

```js
// Get a hook function
const {
  useState
} = React;

const Example = ({
  title
}) => {
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    price: '',
    duration: '',
    description: '',
    daysPerWeek: '',
    allExercises: [{
      day: 'Monday',
      exercises: [],
    }, ],
  });

  function addDay() {
    const newExercises = {
      name: 'pushup',
      sets: '12',
      reps: '1',
      link: '',
    };

    const StateCopy = { ...formFields
    }



    const exercises = StateCopy.allExercises.map(item => {
      if (item.day === "Monday") {
        item.exercises.push(newExercises)
      }
      return item
    });
    StateCopy.allExercises = exercises;

    setFormFields({ ...StateCopy
    })
  }

  console.log(formFields)

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    button onClick = {
      addDay
    } >
    Click me <
    /button> < /
    div >
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( <
  Example title = "Example using Hooks:" / >
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator syntex to create copy of deeply nested object properties, and then update the specific one, but this might get ugly as your code grows.

Alternatively, you can use **Immer Library** to update deeply nested properties.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. I structured the data differently.
Since there are known number of days and you could have some id for each of them, you could have:

```
{
    name: '',
    price: '',
    duration: '',
    description: '',
    daysPerWeek: '',
    allExercises: {
      'monday': {
          day: 'Monday',
          exercises: [
            {
              name: '',
              sets: '',
              reps: '',
              link: '',
            },
          ],
       }
    },
  }
```

Then, when you would want to add a day

```
const addDay = (dayId: string, day: string) => {
    setFormFields({
        ...formFields,
        allExercises: {
            ...formFields.allExercises,
            [dayId]: {
                day,
                exercises: [],
            }
        }
    })
}
```

When adding an exercise:

```
const addExercise = (dayId: string, exercise: Exercise) => {
    setFormFields({
        ...formFields,
        allExercises: {
            ...formFields.allExercises,
            [dayId]: {
                ...formFields.allExercises[dayId],
                exercises: [
                    ...formFields.allExercises[dayId].exercises,
                    exercise
                ],
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I also suggest checking out lodash's `_.merge()`, since all this destructuring is a bother.

```
    setFormFields(_.merge(formFields, {
        allExercises: {
            [dayId]: {
                exercises: [
                    exercise
                ],
            }
        }
    }))
```

If you want to render them, you can take the values only (or entries)

```
_.values(formFields.allExercises).map(exercise => <div key={exercise.day}>{...}</div>)
```

```
_.entries(formFields.allExercises).map(([dayId, exercise]) => <div key={dayId}>{...}</div>)
```

I would also suggest `react-hook-form`. Check it out, you can do much more with it.

Answer (score 0):

The demo below gives a basic starting point to solve for adding exercises for specific days and managing state based on extending your example code a bit. This works fine for an arbitrary fixed set of days using your example but also highlights the potential for growing complexity and why other state management solutions exist.

Hopefully this provides some insight into how to begin thinking about managing nested state and potential need for other strategies.

I also encourage you to check out the link at the bottom for some good reading and examples.

### Demo/Example

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-newton-84hqs2

```
import { useState } from "react";

const initialState = {
  allExercises: [
    {
      day: "Monday",
      exercises: [
        {
          name: "",
          sets: "",
          reps: "",
          link: ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  function addExercise(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(e.target);
    const formFields = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
    const newExercise = {
      name: formFields.name,
      sets: formFields.sets,
      reps: formFields.reps,
      link: formFields.link
    };

    const createNewDay = !state.allExercises.find(
      (item) => item.day === formFields.day
    );

    if (createNewDay) {
      setState((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          allExercises: [
            ...prev.allExercises,
            ...[{ day: formFields.day, exercises: [newExercise] }]
          ]
        };
      });
      // else add new exercise to existing day
    } else {
      setState((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          allExercises: prev.allExercises.map((item) =>
            item.day === formFields.day
              ? {
                  ...item,
                  exercises: [...item.exercises, ...[newExercise]]
                }
              : item
          )
        };
      });
    }
  }

  console.log("current exercises state: ", state.allExercises);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={(e) => addExercise(e)}>
        <select name="day" id="day">
          <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
          <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
          <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
          <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
          <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
          <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
          <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="text" name="sets" />
        <input type="text" name="reps" />
        <input type="text" name="link" />
        <button type="submit">Add Exercise</button>
      </form>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setState(initialState)}>
        Reset State
      </button>
      {state.allExercises.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <div>
            <b>{item.day}</b>
          </div>
          {item.exercises.map((exercise, i) => (
            <div>
              <div>exercise {i + 1}</div>
              {Object.entries(exercise).map(([k, v]) => (
                <div>
                  {k}: {v}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Useful Resources/Related Reading

https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/#redux-update-an-object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update to the specifi day if already selected,

```
function addDay(day, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newEx = formFields.allExercises.map((ele) => {
      if (ele.day === day) {
        //you can add exercises here either from a state variable holding exercises for that day/ passing exercier to the button handler itself
        const newEle = { ...ele, exercises: [] };
        return newEle;
      } else {
        return ele;
      }
    });
    setFormFields((pre) => ({ ...pre, allExercises: newEx }));
  }
```

Another version

```
function addDay(day,exercises, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newEx = formFields.allExercises.map((ele) => {
      if (ele.day === day) {
        //you can add exercises here either from a state variable holding exercises for that day/ passing exercier to the button handler itself
        const newEle = { ...ele, exercises: exercises };
        return newEle;
      } else {
        return ele;
      }
    });
    setFormFields((pre) => ({ ...pre, allExercises: newEx }));
  }
```

With a state holding exercises

```
function addDay(day, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newEx = formFields.allExercises.map((ele) => {
      if (ele.day === day) {
        //you can add exercises here either from a state variable holding exercises for that day/ passing exercier to the button handler itself
        const newEle = { ...ele, exercises: stateExercises };//here
        return newEle;
      } else {
        return ele;
      }
    });
    setFormFields((pre) => ({ ...pre, allExercises: newEx }));
  }
```